# Hartl Tutorial: 3.2 Error when i try and clean up my code

Tags: ruby

When i run the test i receive this message(i am guessing it passed), but when i go to local host300 i receive the following on all my pages: No route matches [GET] "/about"

I have been stuck on this for around 4 hours :(

This is the test report i received-

C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_
spec.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_ap
p/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, ex
pecting $end (SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in`depend_on'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in`block in modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in`modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in`helper'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:159:in `default_helper_module!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in`block in inherited'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `class_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in`inherited'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:135:in `inherited'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in`block (2 levels) in
 with'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.13/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/application_cont
roller.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in`depend_on'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in`block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in`block in eager_load!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in`eager_load!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
 (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in`requir
e'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.
rb:1:in`require'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in`run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in`block in autorun'

My Coded Pages:

**helpers\application.helper.rb**

```
 def full_title(page_title)
base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorials Sample App"
if page_title.empty?
    base_title
else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
end
    end
    end
```

**Static_pages_helper.rb**

```
 module StaticPagesHelper
 end
```

**Application.html.erb**

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
 </head>
 <body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb**

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe "Static pages" do

subject { page }

 describe "Home page" do
before { visit root_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sample App') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
 end

describe "Help page" do
before { visit Help_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Help') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
 end

describe "About page" do
before { visit About_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'About') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
 end

describe "Contact page" do
before { visit Contact_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Contact') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

match '/static_pages/home' => 'static_pages#home'
match '/Help',    to: 'static_pages#Help'
match '/About',   to: 'static_pages#About'
match '/Contact', to: 'static_pages#Contact'

root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

**about.html.erb**

```
 <% provide(:title, "About Us") %>
 <h1>About Us</h1>
   <p>
The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
is the sample application for the tutorial.
  </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**contact.html.erb**

```
  % provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>
    Contact Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
   <a href="http://railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
  </p>
```

**help.html.erb**

```
   <% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>Help</h1>
    <p>
Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help page</a>
To get help on this sample app, see the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/book">Rails Tutorial book</a>.
   </p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

 <h2>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
  </h2>

   <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

**utilities.rb**

```
def full_title(page_title)
 base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 if page_title.empty?
 base_title
 else
"#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
 end
 end
```

**application.rb**

```
          require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

      # Pick the frameworks you want:
     require "active_record/railtie"
     require "action_controller/railtie"
     require "action_mailer/railtie"
     require "active_resource/railtie"
   require "sprockets/railtie"
    # require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

     if defined?(Bundler)
    # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
   Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
       # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
       # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
      end

    module SampleApp
   class Application < Rails::Application
   # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

   # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
   # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
   # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

   # Activate observers that should always be running.
   # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

 # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to
 this zone.
  # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
  # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto
 loaded.
  # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

 # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
config.filter_parameters += [:password]

# Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

# Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
# This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
# like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
# config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

# Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
# This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for 
all models
# in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist
 accessible
# parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
 end
```

github address: 
https://github.com/froeal01/sample_app

Trying to starts the server, created with this error:

Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/c
onfig/routes.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (Syntax
Error)

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` to install rspec-rails? Did you restart your server afterwards? Did you do `rake db:test:prepare`. Those are obvious things to try out.

Comment: Hello. Just tried what you suggested and nothing. When i open the localhost (no /home , /about..etc) I get this error:SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#home

C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Comment: other pages still have "Routing Error" No route matches.

Comment: Can you run "rake routes" in your terminal, and paste the response? That might provide a clue.

Comment: Also, could you push to github again? Your routes file up there is currently NOT the one Benjamin suggested, and if that's the case on your computer as well, that is likely the problem.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be canceling out the <body> or <html> tags in your yielded views (about/help/etc), because you're already doing so in application.html.erb. This also isn't causing the problem, but you should still fix it, cause it will do weird things.

Answer (score 0):

Your application helper is missing an `end`.

```
 def full_title(page_title)
   base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorials Sample App"
   if page_title.empty?
     base_title
   else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
   end
 end
```

There's a problem with how you define your routes. Rails routes are all lowercase.

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home",     :to => "static_pages#home"
  get "help",     :to => "static_pages#help"
  get "about",    :to => "static_pages#about"
  get "contacts", :to => "static_pages#contacts"
end
```

Therefore, your routes to the about page should be `about_path` instead.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for commenting. i actually have two ends, but for some reason it did not copy in the code. So i guess that may not be the cause

Comment: Please see my updated response. It would help to format your answers properly also.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thank you for your follow up response. Unfortunately it still does not work. This is the first error i get now: 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)'along with the long list of gem from my original post. I also now receive this when i turn on the server.  Syntax Error in StaticPagesController#about.

Comment: Could you paste the full source of `application.rb`. A link to github would be awesome too.

Comment: Just pasted application.rb and put in my github link. I just did a $git push so i believe everything is up to day. Let me know if there is something else i need to do (as you can tell i am really new). Thank you so much for your help on this, it really means alot :)

Comment: I've edited the routes. I pulled your application, and using the routes I provided in the answer, was about to go to the `/about` path.

Comment: I updated my rail routes with the your code above. However, when i ran $rails s  i received an error message. I have added it to my original post..Sorry...

Comment: I doubt this is causing the problem, because of the capitalization of your error message, but you're also incorrectly capitalizing the paths in your spec. It should be "visit about_path", not "visit About_path".