# Receiving Syntax Error When Adding Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, railstutorial.org

New to RoR; I have received great help here.

Moving through a tutorial here, and I created a new controller.  However, the config/routes file did not automatically update.  Therefor, I made the edit myself and added `get "static_pages/home"` and `get "static_pages/help"`.  However, when I go to the url for the 'Home' page, I'm presented with and error stating:

```
SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#home
```

further stating:

```
/Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/sample_app/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected rails.root: /Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/sample_app
```

Can anyone give me a tip?

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file

Comment: Did not install the .html files with previous command.

Comment: Thanks, dude- appreciate the response.

Comment: IF the syntax error is in static_pages_controller.rb at line 2, please post the specific code snippet.

Comment: It was simply a matter of not having the file in the directory when using a command to create, earlier. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i am not familiar in this .but you can refer this links.....hope this link will helpful.

**[Hartl Tutorial: 3.2 Error when i try and clean up my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621126/hartl-tutorial-3-2-error-when-i-try-and-clean-up-my-code)**

**[displaying two renders in staticpage home in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288925/displaying-two-renders-in-staticpage-home-in-rails-3)**